# Schema.org property to link items to WebPage

Tags: microdata, schema.org

This is my HTML format for all pages:

```html
 <html>
    <head>
      ...
    </head>
    <body>
      <p>...</p>

      <slide>...</slide>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I want to set Microdata for that. Which format of these is correct?

```html
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
<head>
  <meta itemprop="name" content="webpage"/>
</head>
<body>
  <p itemprop="mainContentOfPage" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="article"/>
  </p>

  <slide itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPSideBar">.
    <meta itemprop="name" content="slide"/>
  </slide>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems above code is correct but when I check it on Google lab, it does not show that the `slide` tag is a child of WebPage. This is the result:

```
 Item 
    type:   http://schema.org/webpage
    property:   
    name:   webpage
    maincontentofpage:  
    Item 1

 Item 1
    type:   http://schema.org/article
    property:   
    name:   article

  Item 
    type:   http://schema.org/wpsidebar
    property:   
    name:   slide
```

So I try to solve this issue by adding a new `itemprop`. The best `itemprop` that I could find is 'text' or 'about':

```html
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
<head>
  <meta itemprop="name" content="webpage"/>
</head>

<body>
  <p itemprop="about mainContentOfPage" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="article"/>
  </p>

  <slide itemprop="about"  itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPSideBar">.
    <meta itemprop="name" content="slide"/>
  </slide>
</body>
</html>
```

Now if I test it on Google lab the result is this:

```
Item 
    type:   http://schema.org/webpage
    property:   
    name:   webpage
    about:  Item 1
    maincontentofpage:  Item 1
    about:  Item 2

Item 1
    type:   http://schema.org/article
    property:   
    name:   article

Item 2
    type:   http://schema.org/wpsidebar
    property:   
    name:   slide
```

Apparently the problem is solved and now Google knows 'slide' is a child of WebPage!
But my problem:

I do not feel good. Does this property really fit? ('about' or 'text')

Comment: Note that you must use `http://schema.org/WebPage` (instead of `http://schema.org/webpage`). (And I guess that you are aware that there is no `slide` HTML element.)

Comment: Your second question about `AggregateRating` should probably be an own separate question. If it’s about Google’s behaviour, you should ask it on [webmasters.se].

Comment: thank you. for your second note I will ask in webmasters stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you want to relate the items to the [WebPage](http://schema.org/WebPage), you have to use a property.

For the main content, we have [`mainContentOfPage`](http://schema.org/mainContentOfPage). But what about elements that are not (part of) the main content?

Here’s a discussion about such a generic property for linking a [WebPageElement](http://schema.org/WebPageElement) to WebPage:
[Am I right that WebPage lacks a generic property for linking to WebPageElement?](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs/2014Jan/thread.html#msg91)

There is a [proposal for a `hasPart` property](http://www.w3.org/wiki/WebSchemas/Periodicals,_Articles_and_Multi-volume_Works#New_Properties_for_CreativeWork): "A related CreativeWork that is included either logically or physically in this CreativeWork". This would be a good match, but until it becomes part of Schema.org (if at all), we’d have to use what is already there.

Possible *existing* properties could be:

- [`about`](http://schema.org/about)
- [`citation`](http://schema.org/citation)
- [`mentions`](http://schema.org/mentions)
- [`text`](http://schema.org/text)

`text` has the problem that it expects *Text*, not another item. `citation` is probably, at least according to its description, meant for more specific cases. That leaves us with `mentions` and `about`, but both aren’t really fitting either.

So I’d say: Currently there is no good solution.

Personally, I’d just omit a property and leave the item unlinked (until a suitable property gets added to Schema.org).